# Прокрутка owl carousel до нужного элемента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть календарь http://joxi.ru/E2pq88yCBWX6nA даты сделал через слайдер owl carousel, при открытии календаря необходимо чтоб каруселька прокручивалась к нужному элементу к примеру 22 или 15. Нужно навесить id на этот элемент. Календарь не зациклен, те loop: false, поэтому выбрать центральный не получается.

Answer (score 1):

у них в API есть метод, прокрутка к нужному элементу

```
$('#carousel).trigger('to.owl.carousel', 22);
```

Comment: не совсем так как надо работает, 22 элемент получается скрыт и отчет идем с 23, а надо чтоб именно на 22 был виден

Comment: @ИльяШишлачев Честно, я ниче не понял) В смысле, что если ввести 22, то прокручивает к 23 элементу? Ну так всё правильно, нумерация с 0 начинается

Comment: все ок, спасибо)